# Are there any security risks to send entire url as parameter?

Tags: django, security

Currently I am sending the whole URL as parameter in order to be able to return to same page from where I started .

```
<a href="{% url 'bom_edit' pk=field1.id uri=request.build_absolute_uri %}">Edit</a>
```

Are there any security risks involved with doing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

You could send only the path:

```
<a href="{% url 'bom_edit' pk=field1.id uri=request.path %}">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Yes,  but is there ny difference between sending the path and the whole thing from security point of view?

Comment: Sending only the path you make sure the redirect will be to your own site, if you wirte code to receive a full url and redirect to it, someone could call it with an external host url.

Comment: "A *security* point of view?" No, probably not. However, I think that what Goht is suggesting is: &nbsp; "if you do not intend to *go* 'somewhere else,' do not *mention* 'anywhere else!'" If someone's looking at the HTTP code that's being returned by your web-page, it's a good idea (IMHO) that the URLs should be *relative* unless there's a compelling reason for them to *be* absolute. "Give 'em what they're expecting."